Read-only ldap admin OU
I was asked to create a "technical" (meaning not assigned to a person) LDAP account that can read everything in the directory, but no write permission.
Since I hate non-personal accounts in general, I  prefer to create a quasi-admin OU, like standard
dn:
ou=ldap-admin,dc=TOPDN
but with no read permission, to add individual users to this OU as necessary, as I do with ldap-admin OU.
Does this make sense?
Is it possible?
If possible, how?


I was asked to create a "technical" (meaning not assigned to a person) LDAP account that can read everything in the directory, but no write permission.

"Technical" accounts that are shared between multiple people should indeed be avoided. But the opposite also applies: "personal" accounts that are used by services and other automation should be avoided even more; if the purpose of the account was e.g. to set up replication between two servers, then that absolutely should not use someone's "personal" account.

but with no read permission, to add individual users to this OU as necessary, as I do with ldap-admin OU.

It's possible, but OUs are not a good mechanism for access policies because an account can only be in one at a time. You should use group membership for that purpose.
The configuration is nearly the same for both; it's all expressed through OpenLDAP's ACL language – the olcAccess rules. Where you use by dn= or by dn.exact= to grant some access to a specific account, you can instead use by dn.sub= to instead match all accounts underneath an OU (or some other container), and you can use by group= to match the members of an LDAP groupOfNames.
